# How do you handle Ctrl+Break in Python?

Tags: python, windows, signals

In Python you can handle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> with KeyboardInterrupt, but how do you handle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore it then you can [add a signal handler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.signal) like so:

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGBREAK, signal.SIG_IGN)
```

If you want to gracefully shut down your process then you can create a separate signal handler function that will be called whenever the signal is received like so:

```
import signal

def signal_handler(self, signum, frame):
    print(f"Received {signum}! Shutting down...")
    self.cleanup() # create your own clean up function
    sys.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    signal.signal(signal.SIGBREAK, signal_handler)
    # do stuff here in main
```